# How to check if all values in a board are full using a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code that defines a small board:

```
w= 2
h= 2
board = [[0] * h for i in range(w)]
def printboard():
    for row in board:
        print("  ".join([str(cell) for cell in row]))
```

Now I want to define a function that will print "The board is full" if `board[0][0]!=0 and board[0][1]!=0 and board[1][0]!=0 and board[1][1]!=0`

My code is not working:

```
def checkfortie():
    for i in range(w-1):
        for j in range(h-1):
            if board[i][j]!=0:
                print("It's a tie!")
```

The code will print that there's a tie if even just `board[0][0]=1` and `board[1][0]=1`. Can someone please explain why it's not working?

Comment: It can potentially print `It's a tie!` for every element in the board. Don't you want to wait until the end to declare a tie (i.e. after all loops are completed)?

Comment: The logic of `checkfortie` is wrong. It will print "It's a tie!" if there is any (but not necessary all) `board[i][j] != 0`.

Comment: @PaulRooney Yes, I want the function to print `It's a tie!` only if none of the "slots" in the board are 0.

Comment: @kitman0804 Then how can I alter the code so that it'll print `It's a tie!` if ALL slots are not equal to 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For checking a tie, it will be better check for the first case of an element not filed. Doing it this way will allow you to stop the check as soon as it's determined that it is not a tie. Doing it the other way requires iterating over the entire board each time.

```
def checkfortie():
    for row in board:
       for square in row:
           if square == 0:
               return False # once you have found a single tile not filled, you can stop checking

    return True # loop completed without finding an open tile


if checkfortie():
   print("It's a tie")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your intent is to check all of them collectively but instead, you are checking each individually.

Try something like this instead. Here's a solution where I changed your code as little as possible.

```
def checkfortie():
    tie = True
    for i in range(w):
        for j in range(h):
            if board[i][j] == 0:
                tie = False
    if tie:
        print("It's a tie!")
```

A simpler way may be to flatten the array:

```
def checkfortie():
    return all(x == 1 for row in board for x in row)

if (checkfortie()):
    print("It's a tie!")
```

Note, that in your original code, you are subtracting 1 from w and h. That's not needed and is actually creating issues. Try running this:

```
for i in range(w-1):
    for j in range(h-1):
        print(i, j)
```

and you'll see that it only prints 0,0

```
for i in range(w):
    for j in range(h):
        print(i, j)
```

the above code will print

0 0
0 1
1 0
1 1

Comment: Hmmm. I tried this but it'll still print `It's a tie!` if `board[0][0]=1` and `board[1][0]=1` even if `board[0][1]=0`

Comment: @Dibbs Sorry, you were looping incorrectly and I got too focused on the other issue and didn't fix that one. Both should be fixed now.